# summaryBy and lots of variables

Tags: r

I want to use summaryBy and use three grouping variables (right side of my formula), but 170 or so variables to be summarised (in my case calculate median). How can I specify them all in the same formula?

Instead of typing out

```
var1+var2+var3...
```

etc. I thought I could make a string like that. That was a whole project in itself, but at least I now have a string stored that is all the variables with plus signs in between. I call it `z1`.

Now, simply asking for `z1` or even `paste(z1)` in my summaryBy script does not work:

```
d <- summaryBy(paste(z1) ~ year + month + ID,
                data=.., 
                FUN=c(median,sum), 
                na.rm=TRUE)
```

Giving error:

> Error in tapply(currVAR, rh.string.factor, function(x) { :
>   arguments must have same length

I imagine it has to do with the fact that in summaryBy I specify my data. But I am new to R and therefore am not able to comprehend the problem beyond this.

I also tried a different method, as suggested:

```
d<-summaryBy(paste(z1,"~year+month+ID"),
                data=..,
                FUN=c(median,sum),
                na.rm=TRUE)
```

This instead gives the error

> Error in .get_variables(formula, data, id, debug.info) :    'formula'
>   must be a formula or a list

So not sure how to go form there.

From the help documentation:

> Computations on several variables is done using cbind( )
>   summaryBy(cbind(Weight, Feed) ~ Evit + Cu, data=subset(dietox, Time >
>   1), FUN=fun)

And testing this, this time with z2 being a string of all my variables separated by commas.

```
d<-summaryBy(cbind(z2)~year+month+ID,
                data=..,
                FUN=c(median,sum),
                na.rm=TRUE)
```

or the variation

```
d<-summaryBy(cbind(paste(z2))~year+month+ID,
                data=..,
                FUN=c(median,sum),
                na.rm=TRUE)
```

Both give the argument length error as my original try above.

Another suggestion (thanks @akrun):

```
d<-summaryBy(as.formula(paste(z1,"~year+month+ID")),
                data=..,
                FUN=c(median,sum),
                na.rm=TRUE)'
```

Reminder: `z1` is variables with pluses in between.

In this case, R gives no error. It seems like it is either loading or wating for additional commands. Console looks like this:
[Screenshot of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkJFq.png)
Without the `>` at the bottom.. What does that mean?

### ***Final edit and solution:***

The `as.formula` approach worked! Thanks so much! I now understand that if console does not have an arrow at the bottom, like in my screenshot above, it means R is computing haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `paste` is just wrapping around only the variables of interest.  It can be

```
library(doBy)
summaryBy(as.formula(paste(z1, "~ year + month + ID")),
            data=.., 
            FUN=c(median,sum), 
            na.rm=TRUE)
```

where

```
z1 <- paste0('var', 1:3, collapse=" + ")
```

---

Using a reproducible example from `?summaryBy`

```
data(dietox)
dietox12    <- subset(dietox,Time==12)
fun <- function(x){
   c(m=mean(x), v=var(x), n=length(x))
 }

out1 <-  summaryBy(cbind(Weight, Feed) ~ Evit + Cu, data=dietox12,
       FUN=fun)

out2 <-  summaryBy(Weight +  Feed ~ Evit + Cu, data=dietox12,
                      FUN=fun)

z2 <- paste(c("Weight", "Feed"), collapse=" + ")
out3 <- summaryBy(as.formula(paste(z2,  "~ Evit + Cu")), data=dietox12,
       FUN=fun)
identical(out1, out2)
#[1] TRUE
identical(out1, out3)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to @akrun, the following code now works:

```
d<-summaryBy(as.formula(paste(z1,"~year+month+ID")),
              data=..,
              FUN=c(median,sum),
              na.rm=TRUE)
```

The reason I thought it didn't at first is because it took so long to compute! It is a massive dataset after all. Edited my original post but left all my tries in there, including the question about the "missing arrow" which I now understand to mean that R is working. Hard. Thanks!